# Several drop down list input to one field table

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

Guys anyone can help me solved this code, i have several drop down list which i want to insert into table. but i need to insert it into one field only, anyone have a brilliant idea how to do it:)

this is example for drop down list.

```
<select name="level1" style="width:225px;">
<option value=0 selected></option>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$q  = "SELECT attribute_id,attribute_name FROM attribute ";
$result = $db->query($q);
while ($row1 = $result->fetch()){
  echo "<option value='$row1[attribute_name]'>$row1[attribute_name]</option>";
}
?>
</select>


<select name="level1" style="width:225px;">
<option value=0 selected></option>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$q  = "SELECT attribute_id,attribute_name FROM attribute ";
$result = $db->query($q);
while ($row1 = $result->fetch()){
  echo "<option value='$row1[attribute_name]'>$row1[attribute_name]</option>";
}
?>
</select><br>

<select name="level1" style="width:225px;">
<option value=0 selected></option>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$q  = "SELECT attribute_id,attribute_name FROM attribute ";
$result = $db->query($q);
while ($row1 = $result->fetch()){
  echo "<option value='$row1[attribute_name]'>$row1[attribute_name]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Your code doesn't do any inserting at all. All it does is echo the same dropdown list 3 times.

Comment: that's why, i dont know how to insert all the value from drop down list into database. because i need to capture the all of its into one field in database

Comment: What table are you trying to insert into, and how should multiple inputs be combined into one column?

Comment: Please edit your question with additional details, don't do it in comments.

Comment: the table are ID, level1, level2, level3, level 4. so the question is i have form 11 drop down in level 1, 11 drop down in level 2, and so the other level 3 and 4, how do u suggest me to insert it?

Comment: I still don't understand. You haven't described your table structure. What are you trying to insert where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your select levels each need a different name
and a form to go into, with a submit button as well...
So like this....

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
 <select name="level1[]">
  <!--Your database options lists-->
 </select>
 <select name="level1[]">
  <!--Your database options lists-->
 </select>
 <select name="level1[]">
  <!--Your database options lists-->
 </select>     
 <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Then when you pick all three and hit submit it goes to process.php
Which is this file...

```
<?php

  $levels = implode(",", $_POST['level1']);

  //Now you have a string called $levels
  // Which contains a comma seperated list, to insert into db / one field

  //Insert into your table...change your table and field names to real values...

  $sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (attributes) VALUES (:attributes)";
  $q = $db->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array(':attributes'=>$levels));
  ?>
```

This will process the form...

Notice the $levels variable...thats the string to pass into the db, built from your select boxes.

You can build it two ways...

Either string concatenation.
Like this...

```
$levels = $_POST['level1'][0].",".$_POST['level1'][1].",".$_POST['level1'][2];
```

Or build an array and implode, into comma seperated list..
Like this...

```
$levels = implode(",", $_POST['level1']);
```

Either way...youll end up with a comma seperated string to enter into your database...

YOURE WELCOME :)

Comment: wow..thanks, that was i was looking for:) thanks, i have one more question is it possible if i have the same name for all of its? like all name will be level1 only?

Comment: No your selects need to be different names, as theyll be storing different values, but no harm in naming the column that they go into as level1, and just name your selects something like level1-a level1-b level1-c or something along those lines

Comment: i see, thanks for your help. really appreciate it. so i need to add array string to name also right? like name="level1[]"

Comment: actually scratch my last comment, yes you can name them all level1....just as you show above....<input name="level1[]">   Then in your PHP file, just implode that array $_POST['test']....to get the string...  Ill edit the code above to reflect....if you upvote me :)

Comment: Code is good to go, reflects changes we just talked about :)

Comment: i'd love to upvote you but i think i need 15 rep to vote someone.

Comment: Once you have enough rep points, come back and accept this as an asnwer...Id be grateful ;)