# Explain this SQL code in PHP script

Tags: php, sql

I found this piece of code from an answer on [Several drop down list input to one field table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035861/several-drop-down-list-input-to-one-field-table). It really seems like something I can use in my current project. The current project is about populating a table with two dropdown boxes (which are populated themselves with tables). However, I don't understand what personal changes I need to do in order to make it work. attributes? :attributes? Can someone make sense of it?

```
  $levels = $_POST['level1'][0].",".$_POST['level1'][1];

  //Now you have a string called $levels
  // Which contains a comma seperated list, to insert into db / one field

  //Insert into your table...change your table and field names to real values...

  $sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (attributes) VALUES (:attributes)";
  $q = $db->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array(':attributes'=>$levels));
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:attributes` is a bound parameter in a PHP [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which inserts a row into a table with an *attributes* field, setting just that field.

Comment: I am using two dropdown boxes and want to enter their information through this code. How would I use this to do that?

Comment: @Infinitewin please update the question to mention the two dropdown boxes and any other information, about what you want to achieve with the current project.